# Show chuncked list of files in folders with PROPFIND

Tags: curl, webdav

We're using PROPFIND request to get list of all files in specific folder.

```
curl --location --request PROPFIND 'https://example.com/some_folder' \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic eHh4Onl5eQ=='
```

But in some folders we have about 1M files and request timeout.
Is there any way to set start position and file count limit per request?

Comment: you don't have to do that `Authorization: Basic eHh4Onl5eQ==` thing manually, you can just do  `curl --basic --user 'xxx:yyy'` ^^

Comment: Thanks. It just for example. I make request from PHP, it generates right request.

Comment: in PHP it would be ```curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=>CURLAUTH_BASIC, CURLOPT_USERPWD=>'xxx:yyy'));```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC6578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578) *could* be used for paging, but I would bet that support for this is somewhat rare.

Comment: It looks like solution Could you add one example of usage and i will mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 3):

resuming incomplete downloads really isn't curl's thing, it's wget's thing (curl does not have native support for automatically retrying/resuming incomplete downloads, but wget *does* support it. to do the same thing in curl, you would need some scripting language alongside curl, like php/python/whatever)

by default curl downloads to stdout, and wget downloads to files, to get wget to download to stdout, add the argument `-O-` , wget does curl's equivalent of `--location` by default, so no translation needed there, `--request PROPFIND` translates to `--method=PROPFIND`,  and `--header 'Authorization: Basic eHh4Onl5eQ=='` roughly translates to `--auth-no-challenge --http-user='xxx' --http-password='yyy'`  , putting it all together we get

```
wget --tries=10 -O- --method=PROPFIND --auth-no-challenge --http-user='xxx' --http-password='yyy' 'https://example.com/some_folder'
```

which should automatically resume the download up to 10 times before giving up, which you can change with the `--tries=10` argument

for completeness, here's the request wget will send with the above invocation:

```
PROPFIND /some_folder HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.1 (cygwin)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Authorization: Basic eHh4Onl5eQ==
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

> Is there any way to set start position and file count limit per request?

.. having skimmed RFC1918 and RFC5689, i don't think so; it's HTTP so you can issue `HTTP Range requests` to download only parts of the list, but then you won't be able to parse it as well-formatted XML, you'll have to fuzzy-parse it like browsers parse HTML.. (PS libxml2 has good support for parsing broken XML, and PHP has great bindings for libxml2, probably wouldn't be difficult to fuzzy-parse with PHP's DOMDocument::loadHTML() & co)